# How to persist all versions of an entity by JPA?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I am working on auditing the changes of an entity, say PersonEntity.
Existing codes support creating or editing a person's profile and persisting the corresponding PersonEntity. If editing, it will update the PersonEntity in database. It also supports get query of the persons based on a few properties like age. Furthermore, it also provides API to set the "created by", "updated by" and "updated time" - generally it is quite auditable.

My work is to make it even more auditable by persisting all the old versions of a PersonEntity. I think I have two options:

1. Persist a new PersonEntity even if editing. In that way, all versions of PersonEntity are in the database. I should also, 1) add a property in the PersonEntity to indicate whether it is the up-to-date one; 2) when creating or updating PersonEntity, I need to set that flag; 3) change all the query methods to only get PersonEntity that is up-to-date.

In my view that is not a good option since 3) will cause a bunch of code change, and will slow down the query as well.

2. Creating a new class with the same property as PersonEntity, say PersonAuditEntity. When creating or updating PersonEntity, always persist one new PersonAuditEntity.

But in that way, two similar classes are existing in the same time. My initial solution is to simply wrap a PersonEntity into PersonAuditEntity, but it seems that JPA does not support embed an entity in another entity. Is that right?

Any other suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hibernate Envers is what you're looking for. http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you take a look at [Hibernate ORM Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)? This supports auditing the entities like for eg:

```
@Audited
private String name;
```

Will record changes to name atribute for the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Another option.

Add a new column which gets set to inactive when the row is replaced with a new one. Only add new rows and never update a row.

All selects need to use an additional where clause "and inactive = false"

Comment: Thanks for your answer but looks like this is my first option. I need to add such clause into each method with a selection, and I'm afraid the addition will lead to performance degradation. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it is same as your option 1. Apologies. It does have performance issues which are relative to your database and the number of rows. If your talking thousands I wouldn't worry about it, millions would be a concern. You could also look at triggers to copy old data to a different table which is a little similar to your second option.